# Route::bind throwing NotFoundHttpException on non existent resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

This Route::bind() is throwing a NotFoundHttpException when the resource does not exist,

```
Route::bind('layout', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Layout::where('id', $value)->first();
});
```

The full routing for the layout resource is as follows,

```
Route::model('layout', 'Layout');

Route::bind('layout', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Layout::where('id', $value)->first();
});

Route::resource('layout', 'LayoutController');
```

I have several resources with the exact same routing configuration that do not throw this exception when the resource does not exist. Why would this be happening with just one route configuration that is identical to many others? I handle the resource not existing in the controller for all of these other resources.

Here is the full error,

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 113:
No query results for model [App\Layout].
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `Route::model('layout', App\Layout::class);`
2. You don't need to use both `Route::model` and `Route::bind`, choose the one that best suits your need and I think `Route::model` works just fine for your case
3. Register your route models and/or route bindings in your `RouteServiceProvider` class, not your `routes.php` file

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am however getting the same error. The full error is, NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 113: No query results for model [App\Layout]

Comment: Try deleting the Route::model and using Route::bind instead

Comment: Removed Route::model() and moved all Route::bind() calls from web.php to app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot() Still getting the very strange double standard of only this resource raising this exception when others pass an empty resource to my controllers...

Comment: Alright. Here is a twist to this senerio. If I change my route from "layout" to "layou". It works.... Using Route::resource('layou', 'LayoutController'). Why would using "layout" mess anything up.